# What is the Parent of a ViewController placed as SubView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, subview

I have a `ViewController` where I have placed another `ViewController` on one of it's SubView. In that `ViewController` (placed in SubView) I need to go to another `ViewController` on a click event. But when I can `self.navigationController` `pushViewController` method , My log says It's pushed but Screen is not changing.

My attached image depicts the scene , Match Details is the host ViewController. White rectangle is a UIView , and the guest `ViewController` is placed within this white rectangular View. When I click on the round button (Click written) , then another `ViewController` should replace the Host `ViewController`.

It's a complex application , so pasting codes here should not be a good idea. Just a few explanation would help me a lot , I can fix the codes myself. Some some hint required about my mistake.

[image]

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: maybe you should try to call his parent view controller navigation controller

Comment: I have already tried that. But it's parent ViewController is null. No Idea why.

Comment: interesting... another way you could try is to create you custom init method for your subview viewcontroller, where you pass the main viewcontroller, so you could use that to present a new view controller

Comment: check whether self.navigationController is nil or not? try pushing like     [self presentViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>]

Comment: @LucaIaco its not a good idea because using ARC, they wont be deallocated as there is looping reference.

Comment: @santhu , before I posted , I tried what your said like pushing as Modal ViewConteoller. In that case, New VC appears as Modal but doesn't take full screen , it's upto NavigationBar with "Match Details".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add view of viewController as subview you need also register your viewController as child view controller for parentViewController.

Example:

```
UIViewController *mainVC = [UIViewController new];
UIViewController *childVC = [UIViewController new];

[mainVC addChildViewController:childVC];
[mainVC.view addSubview:childVC.view];

UIViewController *parentVC = childVC.parentViewController;
```

Here *parentVC* is *mainVC*.

Comment: Hello @malex , I have managed to get it working. I have taken a ParentVC property in childVC and set this property like this childVC.parent = self when I attach childView as a subview. Not sure how good solution it is but at least it's working. :) You can do necessary editing , I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can make it and it works to. But I wrote the canonical way (by Apple) to make connection between embedded view controllers.

Comment: did you try my approach?

Comment: Ya , Firstly I got it working by the solution I told you above. Actually my scenerio was a bit complex , so another issue arose at a leter time. Your approach or solution is correct. That helped me fixing my codes. Everything is working great now. Thanks a lot.